# PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for:, handler:) does not calls handler block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, photokit

I use [new API for requesting of access](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/3616053-requestauthorization) for an assets library of a user:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { 
                [weak self] (status:PHAuthorizationStatus) in
                print("called");
            }
```

iOS displays alert with access levels:
[image: Alert with access levels]

If the user selects `Select Photos...`, iOS will show a picker:
[image: the images picker]

If user swipes down on a title of the picker, the photos library will not call the handler block.

Implementation of the `photoLibraryDidChange`

```
 func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: (PHChange)) {
        guard let fetchResult = self.fetchResult else {
            return
        }
        if changeInstance.changeDetails(for: fetchResult) != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.delegate?.photosLibraryChanged(self)
            }
        }
    }
```

Does someone faced with this situation? And how I can fix it?

Example: https://github.com/K-Be/NewInPhotoKitInIOS14

Comment: But you, as a user, did not request authorisation yet, because no photo selected, actually you performed cancel (by swiping down), so no callback performed. By my vision it behaves as expected.

Comment: if application will be relaunched, the access level will be limited :(

Comment: Also, If I asks access level in Curren session, it also will be limited. But in current logic, I wait wile the user makes decision about the access level for my application.

Comment: Also, if the user preformed cancel by press the cancel button, the handler will be called.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov have you implemented `photoLibraryDidChange` method? The most common mistake is to PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization and do not implement  `photoLibraryDidChange` method.

Comment: Yes, I have. I've implemented it in the data source.

Comment: Edit your question and show your implementation.

Comment: Did you call `PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)` in viewDidLoad? Does your controller conform to `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver`?

Comment: Yeap. But it does not matter.

Comment: It does. If you request authorization it will change the assets available. You said that if you quit and open again the access level changes

Comment: it is interesting, I'll try to check it :)

Comment: this might help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrarychangeobserver

Comment: photoLibraryDidChange is not called in this case :(

Comment: You did check if it is equal to nil but did not get the result. `if let changes = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: fetchResult) {` `// Keep the new fetch result for future use.`  `fetchResult = changes.fetchResultAfterChanges`

Comment: I inserted break point there.

Comment: I haven't implemented limited authorization but your `photoLibraryDidChange` implementation doesn't look correct

Comment: Sorry, it is other discussion (about implementation of photoLibraryDidChange), and I can tell why it should asks changeDetails and so on, but in other discussion. Also for local check, I add subscription to changes in next line where I ask access.

Comment: you are not fetching Assets inside your closure after requesting authorization

Comment: In the closure Access notify delegate about results, and delegate asks DataSource to fetch assets. (I do not like BVC, and prefer to divide an application to blocks, I you want I can show how it works).